# Queries and conditions in sql store procedure or in functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, qsqlquery, sql-query-store

How can i select only that sentence that contains searched word not a whole documents content . I am using following query but getting whole document or pdf file content .

note : I am using full text search in SQL Server.

```
SELECT column  
FROM DocumentDetailContent  
WHERE CONTAINS(DocumentText,'lesson');
```

Here I just want particular sentence that contains 'lesson'.

OR

If some one searched lesson*

it should return lesson math , lesson english , lesson arabic whatever .

Any suggestion will be appreciated because it can be useful for me and anyone other . thanks

Comment: You can create a variable and do it in procedure. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Actual problem is to search content in file using store procedure

Comment: @NEER I am editing question to make it simple

Comment: Screenshots are a horrible way for us to understand what you're asking. Please post sample data, expected results, and what you've tried. Please make the sample data text in the question, not a link out somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do that with a `LIKE` query - essentially:

```
declare @query nvarchar(100) = N'helpful';
select Id from DocumentDetailContent
where DocumentText like N'%' + @query + N'%'
```

However, it sounds like ["full text search"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) might be a better database option. However, I'd question whether sql server is really the right solution for this - "Elasticsearch" or a similar text index server might be far better.

Comment: .thanks for suggestions . yup i agreed with you strongly . i like elastic search and that is really far better approach. but time is short for me and there is recommended sql server and i will prefer full text search . i am not sure about like because its performance is slow . can we use full text search for this purpose and i need some good and easy resource like video tutorial to understand full text search .

Comment: "can we use full text search for this purpose" yes, but it will take more space than I have here; read the docs

Comment: SELECT DocumentDetailId,DocumentText,IsActive   
FROM DocumentDetailContent  
WHERE CONTAINS(DocumentText,'textile');

Comment: so now how can i make store procedure and get both tables data using joins . its my last problem . thanks

Comment: @nailanaseem so... do those things?

Comment: .@marcgravel can i use JOIN with full text search ?

Comment: .@marcgravel when i run simply that gives me good results but when i use joins that does not give me results . why ?should i edit the question to show you .?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134594/discussion-between-naila-naseem-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: .@marc I am getting this error on sql azure .  DBCC command 'CALLFULLTEXT' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

Comment: @nailanaseem there are some subtle feature differences in hosted providers - you can't use some custom word lists, for example, IIRC; however the FTS feature itself has been supported for 2 years. If it persists and you can't figure it out, I suggest you contact the azure support folks.

Comment: .@Marc I have solved that issue . can you now tell me  "is CONTAINS can be use for Regex"

Comment: @nailanaseem have you tried it? have you read the documentation?

Comment: .@marc Yes i Have solved that . so now please help to find "sentance that contains specific word in file " .

Comment: simply i dont want to get full document which has word , no , just i want that sentence .